# copy on premise sql server hosted on linux server to Azure datalake using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to copy the table from on premise sql database hosted on linux server to Azure datalake using azure data factory. Self hosted integration works natively for windows system. Can someone share your thoughts or work around to achieve this requirement?

Regards
Aravindan

Comment: Do you have a Windows Server you can create the SHIR on that can access the database on linux server.  The SHIR does not need to be on the same server you want access to, in fact it probably should not be.  The SHIR just needs to be able to access the resource you want to access from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved as the SHIR has below system requirements and in order to connect to onPrem data sources ADF requires SHIR.

[image]

A workaround could be using SSIS packages in Linux to extract the data. For more information, please refer to this documentation: [Extract, transform, and load data on Linux with SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-ssis?view=sql-server-ver16)